# ID auto increment and update in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Inside my SQL Server database I got this as my `ID` for example `SSK0000001`.

I want it to auto-increment in my system and also the last number of `ID` e.g."1" (after another new record it will become `SSK0000002`) is update in my SQL Server database.

I know it can be done with set auto-increment inside database but now my `ID` is `nchar`.

Anyone could help will be appreciate.

Comment: you can define a trigger on your table that you want to auto update.

Comment: if SSK is allways the same, hardcode it to your program or querry with concatination, and use autoincrement field to do the job for you. Much faster then any procedure/trigger you can write. If not, add column as varchar, and make PK ('ssk column', 'autoincrement column')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast right side to int and increment:

```
declare @next int
select @next = convert( int, right( max( id ), 7 ) )  + 1
from your table
```

then insert as:

```
insert into ... (Id, ...)
values (   'SDK' + right( '0000000' + rtrim(ltrim( str( @next ) ) ), 7 ), ... )
```

But this is the most **dirty solution** as you can take:

- This cause a lot of database locks (because aggregation function)
- Slowest than autoincrement
- Lot of code to keep.

**I suggest to you to move to an autoincrement data type**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's work what I want !!!                 But now i want it can be **auto increment** AND                  **UPDATE** the last number to database as I got a table is to store the last ID's number while got new record entered. Thanks in advanced~

Comment: can you advise on how to make the ID auto increment after the SDK and 0000000 joined? Thanks alot!

Comment: as: `@next = coalesce( convert( int, right( max( id ), 7 ) )  + 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a calculated column based on an auto-increment column. Should work from sql server 2005 upwards.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST1](
    [AUTO_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID]  AS CAST(('SSK'+replace(str([AUTO_ID],(7),(0)),' ','0')) AS NCHAR(10)) PERSISTED,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](10) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO TEST1 (NAME) VALUES ('NAME1')
INSERT INTO TEST1 (NAME) VALUES ('NAME2')
INSERT INTO TEST1 (NAME) VALUES ('NAME3')

SELECT * FROM TEST1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that come to my mind is

- explode your ID so you separate SSK from the number
- increment the number
- then stick back SSK with the number